# Styled-componenst con bootsrtap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, reactjs

Estoy investigando styled-components. Mi pregunta es como se deberian manejar con bootstrap 4?
Al crear la const con los estilos nuevos deberia agregarles los que vienen con bootstrap por default?
Si por ejemplo le quiero agregar un background a la clase container, seria correcto hacerlo como en mi ejemplo?
y en dicho caso como se maneja el tema d elos breakpoints?

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: red // inventado 
`
```

gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto lo que intentas solo que necesitas usar el componente que quieres sobreescribir, por ejemplo tomando tu ejemplo y lo que quieres hacer:

```
const StyledContainer = styled(Container)`
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: red // inventado`
```

Asi Container tendra sus estilos por default y los que tu estas cambiando. Y no, no tienes que agregar los estilos que ya vienen en los componentes de bootstrap, solo agregas los que tu quieres cambiar.

Cuando necesites sobreescribir un componente tienes que ponerlo dentro de parentesis `styled(Button)`, al contrario de un tag normal `styled.button` .